# How to echo the name of the argument but not its value

Tags: bash, function, arguments

Simple function:

```
arg1=5
arg2=10

test(){
   cn_add $1      
   cn_add $2
   echo "$1 $2"  <--this is where my problem is
}
```

And I want the following output:

```
test arg1 arg2 outputs:
add 5 to cn
OK
adding 10 to cn
OK
arg1 arg2
```

How can I have 2 instances of the arguments, one for their value, and another one for their naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe?

```
#You can remove this up to #/remove - it is only for testing   
cn_add() {
   echo add $1 to cn && echo OK
}
#/remove

test(){
   cn_add ${!1}      #evaluate the variable what's name is in $1
   cn_add ${!2}
   echo "$1 $2"  #this is where my problem was
}

arg1=5
arg2=10

test arg1 arg2    #call with the name of variable (not with a value like $arg1)
```

produces:

```
add 5 to cn
OK
add 10 to cn
OK
arg1 arg2
```

The `${!1}` is called as `indirect variable`

One comment:

Usually **not** a good practice name the shell functions with same name as the shell builtins. The `test` **is** a shell builtin - therefore in the 1st version i called it as `xtest`.

Comment: Cn_add is a normal command, not script :(
so i need this: test=5, echo $test (produces 5), but i need a command that produces "test", and not its value..

Comment: @aprin I answered a question EXACTLY as you asked... If your needs are different, re-edit your question...

Comment: Gee, i didn't notice the comments in the beginning...
You're correct....relax though! :)) Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @aprin glad to help - enjoy ;)